# How do I select only summary info from a series of entries in an MS Word document?

Tags: ms-word

I have a series of country walks (actually something more technical - this is just an analogy), contained in a single document in MS Word.  Each walk consists of: (1) Title (2) Summary (length, difficulty) (3) Detailed Instructions. I want to make a separate document consisting only of the Tile and Summary in each case.

I tried making the Title and Summary a different font, e.g. Verdana instead of Arial. But "Select Text With Similar Formatting" does NOT work because the Verdana text also contains different colours, underlines, font sizes, etc. I am expecting I may need a macro, since I want this to be automatic, as a single operation.

Comment: Use styles, paragraph and/or character to mark your special text. Styles is a key part of Word documents structures. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work. "Similar Formatting" means "Similar Style" after I created one.

Answer (score -1):

### Use Styles, paragraph and/or character to mark your special text. Styles is a key part of Word document structure.

This is but one use of Styles in Word.

You can search for similar formatting or in Advanced Find search for a particular style.

Styles are a fundamental component of any Word document and using Word for important projects without at least a basic understanding of their use is shooting yourself in the foot! Here is my page on the [Importance of Styles in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm).

Comment: FYI the question is off-topic here as it has nothing to do with programming. Aside from that: You haven’t provided any specifics other than a general “use xyz” followed by a link to your own page. This is not the way.

Comment: The OP indicated in comments that the idea of using styles was what was needed. OP was seeking a programming solution that is not necessary. Any experienced Word user is going to be at least familiar with the concept of styles. The link was not to solve the problem but to lead to more information.

Comment: OP showed zero work. There's nothing to answer. Plus, this isn't the place to answer non-programming questions.